# Printing a pointer of an 3D array element using pointer arithmetics

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, pointer-arithmetic

I am testing how to use array name with pointer arithmetic to access an array elemnets and I have come up with this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    // definition of array using designators
    int a[2][2][2] = {
        [0] = {[0] = {1, 2}, [1] = {3, 4}},
        [1] = {[0] = {5, 6}, [1] = {7, 8}}
    };

    printf("7th  element (pointer):  %p\n", *(*(a + 1) + 1) + 0);
    printf("8th  element (pointer):  %p\n", *(*(a + 1) + 1) + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Although program works and prints everything correct:

```
7th  element (pointer):  0x7ffd4b09a1c8
8th  element (pointer):  0x7ffd4b09a1d0
```

I get warnings at compile time saying something like this for every line where I use `%p` place holder inside `printf()`:

```
warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("7th  element (pointer):  %p\n", *(*(a + 1) + 1) + 0);
                                   ~^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                   %ls
```

So at the first glance it looks like I have to simply cast the pointers to `(void *)` and if I do this and change line:

```
printf("8th  element (pointer):  %p\n", *(*(a + 1) + 1) + 1);
```

With this line:

```
printf("8th  element (pointer):  %p\n", (void *)(*(a + 1) + 1) + 1);
```

I get a warning:

```
warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  printf("8th  element (pointer):  %p\n", (void *)(*(a + 1) + 1) + 1);
                                                             ^
```

and compiler calculates a different address for 8'th element and this address is only 1 byte larger than preceeding elemnet's address:

```
7th  element (pointer):  0x7ffd9e5e1bf8
8th  element (pointer):  0x7ffd9e5e1bf9
```

I also tried to fix it like this *(added one more braces)*:

```
printf("8th  element (pointer):  %p\n", (void *)((*(a + 1) + 1) + 1));
```

and warning was gone, but address is still calculated differently:

```
7th  element (pointer):  0x7ffca6c6c468
8th  element (pointer):  0x7ffca6c6c470
```

It looks like compiler needs pointer type to calculate the addresses and if I cast it it will not calculate the address corectly. Does anyone have any idea what I can do to remove the warning and get address calculated in a right way?

Comment: `&a[1][1][1]` is a lot easier to read

Comment: It's just a typo. What you wanted to do was add `(void *)(expr)` where `expr` is the expression in the original code. What you actually did was remove a `*`, and then add the cast.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I agree totaly, but, I am interested in all the intestis of the C.

Comment: No worries, array index or pointer notation are entirely equivalent, so either way is fine (though you will loose a lot of newer users with the pointer notation `:)`

Comment: @user3386109 This was not a mistake but my lack of drill.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I personally think it is not only a challenge for newer users. It causes also issues for experienced users as notations like this require more treatment/maintenance to proof if the expressions are correct and for readers what  these expressions are actually doing. With that, precious time is wasted unnecessary. Unless it does not provide a real benefit, I would go with the array indexing version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the arithmetic to be on `int*`, and the value to be look at as `void*`, cast the value *after* you're doing the arithmetics:

```
printf("7th  element (pointer):  %p\n", (void *)((int*)*(*(a + 1) + 1) + 0));
printf("8th  element (pointer):  %p\n", (void *)((int*)*(*(a + 1) + 1) + 1));
```

Comment: Ahh! Wonderful solution! Thank you very much. I was able to omit typecasting to `int` as well and it still worked like this `(void *)(*(*(a + 1) + 1) + 1));`

Answer (score 0):

You can store the pointer into a separate variable and pass it to printf:

```
void *ptr7th = (*(*(a + 1) + 1) + 0);
void *ptr8th = (*(*(a + 1) + 1) + 1);
printf("7th  element (pointer):  %p\n", ptr7th);
printf("8th  element (pointer):  %p\n", ptr8th);
```

using gcc version 9.3.0 with the `-Wall` parameter does not return any warning.